# Is there a counterexample to this metric analog of the side-angle-side (SAS) postulate?

Tags: geometry, metric-spaces, examples-counterexamples, metric-geometry

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space such that for all distinct $x_1, x_2 \in X$:

- For $r \in [0,d(x_1,x_2)]$, there exists a unique $y_r \in X$ such that $d(x_1,y_r)=r$ and $d(x_1,y_r)+d(y_r,x_2)= d(x_1,x_2)$.
- For $r \in (d(x_1,x_2),\infty)$, there exists a unique $y_r \in X$ such that $d(x_1,y_r)=r$ and $d(x_1,x_2)+ d(x_2,y_r)=d(x_1,y_r)$.

For those familiar with the terms, this should be equivalent to an  [externally convex M-space](http://www.doiserbia.nb.rs/img/doi/0350-1302/2014/0350-13021409229S.pdf). As far as I understand, any normed vector space over the reals should satisfy this property.

> Now let's say we have five points $O, A_1, A_2, B_1, B_2$ such that for $i=1,2$, $\rho >1$, $d(O,B_i)=\rho \cdot d(O,A_i)$ and $d(O,B_i)=d(O,A_i)+d(A_i,B_i)$.
>
> **Question:** Then do we have that $d(B_1,B_2)= \rho \cdot d(A_1,A_2)$?

**Attempt:** At first I assumed that the answer to this question would obviously be yes, and that fiddling around with the given information would immediately lead to a proof.

However, I quickly realized that the triangle inequality does not give a tight upper bound for either side of the equation, and I was unable to manipulate it (e.g. using minus signs) to also give me any lower bound. All I found was a common upper bound for $d(B_1,B_2)$ and $\rho \cdot d(A_1,A_2)$: $$d(B_1,B_2) \le \rho \cdot (d(O,A_1) + d(O,A_2))\,, \quad\quad \rho \cdot d(A_1,A_2) \le \rho \cdot(d(O,A_1)+d(O,A_2)) \,. $$ But since this upper bound isn't tight, even if I find a common lower bound as well, it won't be enough to force both quantities to have the same value.

My next thought was to use the hypothesis to identify a unique midpoint $A_3$ between $A_1$ and $A_2$ and a unique midpoint $B_3$ between $B_1$ and $B_2$, then somehow show that $d(O,B_3)=\rho \cdot d(O,A_3)$ and $d(O,B_3)=d(O,A_3)+d(A_3,B_3)$, by using at some point an appeal to uniqueness. Then somehow this would show that $\rho\cdot d(A_1,A_3) = d(B_1,B_3)$ and thus that $d(B_1,B_2) = \rho \cdot d(A_1,A_2)$.

But for any of this argument to work, it seems like I would need the following [equivalent formulation of the parallel postulate/Euclid's axiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarski%27s_axioms#Congruence_and_betweenness):

> Let a line segment join the midpoint of two sides of a given triangle. That line segment will be half as long as the third side.

I was worried that this might be equivalent to the SAS postulate and thus I would have to assume what I wanted to prove. However, [that seems not to be the case](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/5260/side-angle-side-congruence-and-the-parallel-postulate).

Nevertheless, I am still confused about whether this could work, since the [parallel postulate is supposed to be equivalent to the pythagorean theorem](http://www.cut-the-knot.org/triangle/pythpar/PTimpliesPP.shtml), which obviously does not hold in arbitrary normed vector spaces over the reals, whereas I thought my assumptions were *weaker* than a normed vector space over the reals.

So it seems like neither of these obvious approaches would work, which means that instead I should try to find a counterexample. However, all of my intuition for this comes from $\mathbb{R}^n$ with either the Euclidean or the taxicab metric -- cases for which the result is true. Thus I am not sure what direction to look in order to find a counterexample.

Comment: A better metric analogue to the SAS postulate might be Tarski's five segment axiom, where betweenness is interpreted as $B(a,b,c) \iff d(a,b) + d(b,c) = d(a,c)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider $\mathbb{H}^2$ Then $$d(B_1,B_2) > \rho \cdot d(A_1,A_2)$$

Comment: I'm sure this is completely obvious, but I don't follow. Does $\mathbb{H}$ mean the quaternions? What is the metric for $\mathbb{H}$?  Are $A_i, B_i$ completely arbitrary?

Comment: $\mathbb{H}^2=(\{(x,y)|y>0\},\frac{dx^2+dy^2}{y^2} )$ is 2-dimensional hyperbolic space. And it holds for distinct $A_i,\ B_i$

Comment: Oh OK that makes a lot more sense than what I was thinking of. I really appreciate you fixing this for me.